# Solving Fredholm Equation of the second kind

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations

Consider the Fredholm Equation of the second kind,

$$\phi(x) = 3 + \lambda \int_{0}^{\pi} \text{cos}(x-s) \, \phi(s) \,ds$$

Where the analytical solution is found as,

$$\phi(x) = 3 + \frac{6\lambda}{1 - \lambda \frac{\pi}{2}}\,\text{sin}(x)$$

How could one use Mathematica to find a numerical solution to the same integral equation by using the method of successive approximations (i.e. the Neumann series approach)?

Answer (score 11):

Use `DSolve`:

```
PHI = 
  DSolveValue[ϕ[x] == 3 + λ Integrate[ Cos[x - s] ϕ[s], {s, 0, Pi}], ϕ, x]
(*Function[{x}, (3 (-2 + π λ - 4 λ Sin[x]))/(-2 + π λ)]*)
```

The solution can be further used in the form `PHI[x]`.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I use the function Mathematica returns to, say, investigate the convergence of the new $\phi (x)$ function?

Comment: @ user57401 I modified my answer!

Answer (score 5):

Following Weisstein, Eric W. "Integral Equation Neumann Series." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegralEquationNeumannSeries.html, the Neumann series approximation is:

```
n = 10;  (* for example *)
ϕ[x_, 0] = 3;
Do[ϕ[x_, j_] = 3 + λ Integrate[Cos[x - p] ϕ[p, j - 1], {p, 0, π}], {j, n}]
```

The last term in the series `ϕ[x,n]` is the approximation to `ϕ[x]`.

Here is what *Mathematica* returns for `ϕ[x,10]`.

[image: phi_of_ten]

To investigate convergence, I guess we could look at the difference `ϕ[x,n] - ϕ[x]` as `n` gets large, since you know `ϕ[x]`.

Comment: Thank you! When I try to run this, my output is returning the value of 3? How did you get Mathematica to return the series above for \[Phi][10]?

Comment: Please clear out your variables, perhaps with Evaluation:  Quit Kernel:  Local.  To print the final (nth) value: `\[Phi][x, n]`.

Comment: Made some edits to my answer.  Had a couple of typos.  Within a function definition it is `x_`, otherwise `x`.  Also, `\[Phi][x,j]` needs two arguments, one for `x` and one for the `jth` approximation.  Hope its clear.

Comment: @m_goldberg, how do you post symbols rather than the clutzy \[Phi] type of notation here?

Comment: I use halirutan's plug-in. You can learn more about it [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor)

Comment: Wow, that plug-in is over 5 1/2 years old.  Why not just have it built into the editor here?