# Solving Fredholm Equation with composite unknown function

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations

I would like to numerically solve a Fredholm Equation where the unknown function is composite. For example, an equation like the one described in [Solving Fredholm Equation of the second kind](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192434/solving-fredholm-equation-of-the-second-kind) but having composite functions as unknowns.

Consider then the Fredholm Equation:
$$\phi\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-1\right) = 1 + \frac12 \int_{0}^{\pi} \text{cos}\left(x-s\right) \, \phi\left(\frac{s^2}{2}-1\right) \,ds$$
for $x\in[0,\pi]$.

How could one use Mathematica to find a numerical solution?

Comment: The command of Maple 2021 `restart;
evalf(intsolve(phi(t) = 1 + 1/2*int(cos(sqrt(2 + 2*t) - s)*phi(s)/sqrt(2 + 2*s), s = -1 .. Pi^2/2 - 1), phi(t), method = collocation, order = 2));` produces $\phi(t)= 0.1998091304 t^{2}- 0.9895444856 t+ 0.8053645268$. The plot `plot(eval(0.1998091304*t^2 - 0.9895444856*t + 0.8053645268, t = x^2/2 - 1), x = 0 .. Pi)` is strikingly different from the one in the below answer.

Comment: It should be in the above: `restart;
evalf(intsolve(phi(t) = 1 + 1/2*int(cos(sqrt(2 + 2*t) - sqrt(2 + 2*s))*phi(s)/sqrt(2 + 2*s), s = -1 .. Pi^2/2 - 1), phi(t), method = collocation, order = 2));` produces $\phi(t)=- 0.4666943120 t^{2}+ 2.240582170 t+ 1.558351011$. The plot `plot(eval(-0.4666943120*t^2 + 2.240582170*t + 1.558351011, t = x^2/2 - 1), x = 0 .. Pi)` is dramatically different from the below plot.

Comment: The command of Maple 2021 `restart;
evalf(intsolve(phi(t) = 1 + 1/2*int(cos(sqrt(2 + 2*t) - sqrt(2 + 2*s))*phi(s)/sqrt(2 + 2*s), s = -1 .. Pi^2/2 - 1), phi(t), method = collocation, order = 3));` produces $\phi(t)= 0.1526021469 t^{3}- 1.249904734 t^{2}+ 2.400982898 t+ 3.155295017$. One may look at its plot in `x` by `Plot[0.1526021469*t^3 - 1.249904734*t^2 + 2.400982898*t + 
   3.155295017 /. t -> x^2/2 - 1, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 30]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This equation can be solved with Bernoulli polynomials. First we substitute  $y=x^2/2-1$, $t=s^2/2-1$, then define colocation points, solution and system of equations  as follows

```
nN = 12; L = Pi^2/2 - 1; xcol = 
 Table[-1 + Pi^2/2 (j + 1/2)/nN, {j, 0, nN - 1}]; 
v[x_] := Table[BernoulliB[ n, x/L], {n, 0, nN - 1}]; A = 
 Array[a, {nN}]; u[x_] = A . v[x];
eqs = Table[
   u[xcol[[i]]] - 1 - 
    1/2 A . NIntegrate[
       v[t ] Cos[Sqrt[2 (1 + xcol[[i]])] - Sqrt[2 (1 + t)]]/
         Sqrt[2 (1 + t)], {t, -1, L}, AccuracyGoal -> 10], {i, 
    Length[xcol]}];
```

Numerical solution can be evaluated in two step

```
sol = NMinimize[Norm[eqs], A]

sol1 = FindRoot[Table[eqs[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqs]}], 
  Table[{a[i], a[i] /. sol[[2]]}, {i, Length[A]}]]
```

Finally we plot solution

```
Plot[{u[x^2/2 - 1] /. sol1, u[x^2/2 - 1] /. sol[[2]]}, {x, 0, Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> {"FindRoot", "NMinimize"}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "\[Phi]"}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"n = ", nN}]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank you @Alex Trounev. Is there a difference between FindRoot and NMinimize approaches? In theoretical terms, I mean.

Comment: @Mark Please, pay attention, that we use `sol` in `sol1` as initial guess. So, we can consider `NMinimize` as first iteration in numerical solution.  The Newton's iterative method is implemented in `FindRoot`, while `NMinimize`  always attempts to find a global minimum in a given space. Sometimes two solutions are not differ, but in this example there is difference between.

Answer (score 3):

With the transformed integral equation (thanks @Alex Trounev) collocation method(Galerkin method, doesn't need initial guess! )  with a polynomial basis up to order `y^11`

```
g=Function[y, Table[y ^i, {i, 0,  11}]    
i0 = NIntegrate[ g[y] , {y, -1, Pi^2/2 - 1}  ]// Quiet; 
i1 = NIntegrate[Outer[Times, g[y], g[y]], {y, -1, Pi^2/2 - 1} ]// Quiet;  
i2 = 1/2 NIntegrate[Outer[Times, g[y], g[t]] Cos[ Sqrt[2 (1 + y)] - Sqrt[2 (1 + t)]]/Sqrt[2 (1 + t)], {y, -1, Pi^2/2 - 1}, {t, -1,Pi^2/2 - 1} ]// Quiet;
```

leads to a result

```
Plot[LeastSquares[i1 - i2, i0] . g[x^2/2 - 1], {x, 0, Pi},PlotRange -> {0, All}]
```

which shouldn't differ from Alex Trounev's answer (but slightly does).

[image]

The difference might occur because the grid  in Alex Trounev's answer doesn't include the boundaries `y=-1,y=Pi^2/2-1` ?

Comment: It is nice approach (+1), but `NIntegrate` gives large error due to singularity at  `t=-1`, it is why I don't use this point as a colocation point.

Comment: @ AlexTrounev Thanks for the hint! The singularity `t==-1` seems to be integrable, but the condition of matrix `i1-i2` isn't as bad `Det[i1-i2]== O[10^25]` as expected. Perhaps the function basis has to be adapted.